# Overwriting search command in vim

Tags: vim

When writing non-code with vim, I often have the need to search for multiple words that might be separated by a newline instead of a space.

For example, I may want to search for occurrences of "white house", but some occurrences may have a newline between "white" and "house".

I am aware that such multiline search is possible with "\_s" (e.g., "white\_shouse") but it is cumbersome.  I would like to replace the search command such that spaces are treated as "\_s" without me having to type them out.

Is it possible to "remap" the / search command?

Comment: muckabout: What is this _s you are referring to?  It sounds useful...  I have historically used [\s\n]. *edit* - just tried it.  Did you mean \\_s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Define a mapping that will remap, for example, `,s` to `\_s`: `,s` is easier to type:

   ```
       cnoremap ,t \\_s
   ```
2. Define a custom search function that will replace all occurrences of `\s` with `\_s` and use it:

   ```
       function Search(prompt)
           let searchstring=substitute(input(a:prompt), '\\\\s', '\\\\_s', 'g')
           return a:prompt.searchstring."\n"
       endfunction
       nnoremap <expr> <special> / Search('/')
   ```

   or even

   ```
       function Search(prompt)
           let searchstring=substitute(input(a:prompt), ' ', '\\\\_s', 'g')
           return a:prompt.searchstring."\n"
       endfunction
       nnoremap <expr> <special> / Search('/')
   ```

   (this function replaces spaces with `\_s`)